# How to pass a const parameter from a member function into another member function?

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

I have a class

```
 class Foo : Bar {
 public:
 virtual bool function1(const Card &arg1) const{
     function2(arg1);
 }
 virtual void function2(const Card &anotherArg) {
     /* Do stuff with private member variables*/
 }
 private:
 ....
 };
```

"Card" is a class type. I'm getting an error "Member variable function 'function2' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Simple', but function is not marked const."

I'm not quite sure what the problem is. function2 is taking a const as one of the parameters, so it shouldn't be a problem that arg1 is a const because it's not going to be modified. Also, I tried doing this:

```
function2(arg1) const;
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: This compiler-error is impossible with your code-example.

Comment: That's strange. I'm using XCode and it has highlighted the red line. I have omitted a significant portion of my code that I think is unrelated. Maybe it is the omitted portion that is causing a problem?

Comment: What you think is unrelated may not be unrelated. "const &arg1" is not valid C++ code. It's ok to remove irrelevant information, but you should still end up with valid C++ code.

Comment: `const &arg1` certainly isn't valid as a parameter; you're missing the *type*. Likewise for `const &anotherArg`.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to include it,

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry and didn't include some things. Please take a look at it again. Card is just another class

Comment: I guess that this error can only happen if function2 is declared const  `void function2(const &anotherArg) const`

Comment: No, function 2 is not declared const

Comment: const this call only const this. however a non-const this can call the both

Comment: Regardless, the code is still invalid, as `&arg1` is `const Card*`, not `const Card&` as `function2` expects. Please, *please*, don't post fantasy code. Always,  make sure *before you post* that what you post is (a) enough to reproduce the *real* problem for someone that otherwise has *none* of your code , and (b) omits what is *not required* to produce the problem. Regarding the code you have posted, `function2` is non-const, and cannot be called from a `const` member, where upon entry, `this` is indeed `const`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will try to be less hasty next time when reproducing an example that reflects my problem. Do you have any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your shown example, `function1()` is a `const` method. A `const` method can only call other `const` methods. `function2()` is not a `const` method.

This has nothing to do with the actual parameters to each method.

Comment: Is there anyway I can call function2?

Comment: Make it a `const` function itself.

Comment: I cannot because I need function2 to edit private member variables

Comment: @Goldname (a) an incredibly ill-advised `const_cast` (words can't express how wrong this could potentially be), or (b) make the required members [`mutable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) and make `function2` `const` as well. In either case, you had better know what you're doing, and seriously consider the roadblock you've run into as a highly-probable design flaw.

Comment: By definition, a `const` function cannot modify its object. But if it were to call some other non-`const` function, obviously it could. That's why you cannot call it, and why C++ prohibits it. Welcome to C++.

Comment: @Goldname You can overload `function1()` based on `this` pointer `const`-ness.  For example, the function prototypes `virtual bool function1(const Card &arg1);` and `virtual bool function1(const Card &arg1) const;` actually declare two distinct functions, where the first can modify the intance, but the second can't.  This would allow the version of `function1()` called on a non-`const` `Foo` to modify the instance, even though the version of `function1()` called on `const Foo`s wouldn't be able to modify the instances.

Comment: The first version of `function1()` would be allowed to call `function2()`, while the second version wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

const this can only call const this, non-cont this can call the both.
in your code you are calling a non-const this with const this: function one's this is const whereas function 2's this non const thus this is error.

- function 2 can call function however.

to correct your example:

```
class Foo : Bar 
{
     public:
         virtual bool function1(const Card &arg1) const
         {
             function2(&arg1);
         }
         virtual void function2(const Card &anotherArg)const
         {
             /* Do stuff with private member variables*/
         }
     private:
 ....
 };
```

Comment: The problem if I make function2 const is that I will no longer be able to modify private member variables, so I cannot make it const, but I still would like to call function2.

Comment: if you want to modify then reverse for example make function 2 non-const so it can modify member data and let function one const but call function 1 from function 2 not the contrary as you did.

Comment: @Goldname you must pick one or the other. `function1` is declared that it won't modify member variables , so it is not allowed to call a function which does modify member variables.